# Cloud Foundry plugin in eclipse : throwing exception while trying to start application

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am able to connect to Local cloud foundry vm via the cloud foundry server launched through eclipse. But, when i try to start the application below exception is thrown. Does anybody have any insights on this this exception. I am currently using

> Spring Tools Suite Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE and Build Id: 201210061306

Exception stacktrace

> Could not write JSON: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer (through reference chain: org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.domain.CloudApplication["resources"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["sudo"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer (through reference chain: org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.domain.CloudApplication["resources"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["sudo"])

Regards,
Preetham

Comment: Can you give the full stacktrace as well?

Comment: As the above exception is thrown by eclipse editor that is the max stacktrace i can provide to you. The erro is caused by the plug-in org.eclipse.wst.server.core1. 
Install cloud foundry plug-in.
2. Connect to the micro cloud provided by stackato or vmware.
3. Import a application to the running server and start the application.

Comment: thanks. several questions to confirm: 1. did you install the cf extension from STS dashboard? 2. are you using cloud foundry instance or stackato? 3. did you try deploy and start the app to api.cloudfoundry.com?

Comment: 1. Yes, I installed cf plugin STS dashboard.
2. Stackato instance(As per document stackato is built over cloud foundry).
3. Deploying the app to sandbox provided by Acitve State and to local micro cloud via a stackato client works perfectly.

Comment: I dont really use stackato but I guess there is hardly guarantee for stackato targets and apps to work 100% compatible with cf plugin.

Comment: Which version of Stackato are you using? This was a known issue with Stackato 2.2 that was [fixed in 2.4](http://docs.stackato.com/reference/release-notes.html#release-v2-4-october-29-2012).

Answer (score 2):

This was a known issue with Stackato 2.2 that was [fixed in Stackato 2.4](http://docs.stackato.com/reference/release-notes.html#release-v2-4-october-29-2012).

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try targeting to http://api.cloudfoundry.com and see if the CF plugin for eclipse works. It might be code update that made the cf plugin not compatible with stackato.

Also if you could check the logs at .metadata/.log there might be useful info to tell the underlying issue.

Comment: Stackato aims to be completely API compatible with Cloud Foundry (with a few [Stackato-specific extensions](http://docs.stackato.com/api/client.html)). Generally speaking, if it works with Cloud Foundry, it **should** work with Stackato. :)